# Double For loop does not give the expected results?

Tags: infinite-loop

Why does the `j` index start from `2` not `1` in this double `For` loop

```
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i += 1, For[j = 1, j <= 2, j += 1; Print[{i, j}]]]  

{1,2}

{1,3}

{2,2}

{2,3}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for a For loop is:

```
For[start,test,incr,body]
```

But you wrote for "j":

```
For[start,test,incr; body]
```

note the ";". If you replace ; by , it works:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i += 1, For[j = 1, j <= 2, j += 1, Print[{i, j}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between";" and "," inside For?

Comment: ";" means 2 things. First it suppresses the output. Second, two statements separated by ";" are treated as one statement.